# Difference between Cognos Powerplay Client, Powerplay server and Cognos Transformer

Tags: cognos, transformer-model

Can someone please explain the difference between Cognos Powerplay client, Powerplay server and Cognos transformer.

I am trying to install Cognos 10.2 on a server. I have the installation software for the below three, but not sure if these need to be installed and if so in which order.

1.Cognos Powerplay Client
2.Cognos Powerplay server and
3.Cognos Transformer.

I do not have much experience with Cubes. Do I need to install all the above 3 to build OLAP cubes? or Just Cognos transformer is sufficient?

Appreciate your response.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transformer is used to design and build cubes.
Powerplay Client is a desktop tool for reading the cube.
Powerplay Server is exactly what it sounds like.

How you intend for your users to interact with the cubes determines what you need.  You must have Transformer to build cubes.  The others are optional. Users can interact with cubes using the standard studios that come with Cognos BI (Report Studio, etc).  I don't really see any need for the other two.

Comment: Thanks Andrew for the response.